# Using TWIG variables from children template

Tags: symfony, twig

Need to use a variable that is in the parent template.

I have layout:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  {%block content %}
     {% set com = 0 %}
     DEFALUT CONTENT
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And children template:

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
  HOW USE LAYOUT VARIABLE HERE? LIKE: {{ com }}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you posted should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, layout like that: <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  {%block content %}{% set com = 0 %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

Comment: Have you tried invoking `{{ parent() }}` within child template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parent() twig function.

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
  {{ parent() }}
  {{ com }}
{% endblock %}
```

The above code will render a template like :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}
     {% set com = 0 %}
     DEFAULT CONTENT
     {{ com }}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```